# Where should I locate my Git repositories for projects that share common libraries?

Tags: git, repository

I'm just climbing into Git, and have a query about how it will work with the source code structure we use.

Our source is organized like this:

```
C:\Projects\
    Libs\
        <library source files>

    App1\
        <App 1 source files>
        Help\
            <App 1 help sources>  
        Images\
            <App 1 images>
        Cursors\ 
            <App 1 cursors>

    App2\
        <App 2 source files>
        Help\
            <App 2 help sources>  
        Images\
            <App 2 images>
        Cursors\ 
            <App 2 cursors>
```

- I understand that a repo must (should?) live in a folder common to
  all files in a project, so I am looking at putting all my repos in
  `C:\Projects\` right?
- In the rare event that a file is needed for a
  project that is outside the repo tree, what is the accepted way of including
  that?
- If I check out a previous version of `App1`, presumably the
  associated library files it used at the time the previous version had been
  committed will also revert.  What happens when someone else checks out
  `App2` (i.e. how are they alerted that a library file has been reverted
  to a previous version)?

If the above questions make no sense, it's because I don't fully understand how Git works. please feel free to enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a Git specific question. You have the same problem if you use SVN.

Essentially, you have 3 projects not one. app1, app2 and common libs. So put them in 3 different repository.

In addition use a script to compile, build and run. Learn Ant or Gradle. They can manage external files and changing config file for different server environment.

Here is a general rules.

1. Create one repo for each projects.
2. If projects are dependent to each other, package one project and import it to the other project. The concept behind JAR file. That way you can also manage versions. For example p1 is v1 but p2 is v5. The concept behind Maven.
3. If there are common code that both project use /lib/ then create another repo for common_lib. The same as 2) import package to your projects.
4. Always use scripts to compile, build, package and deploy. Learn ANT or Gradle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  There is a slight complication. The setup will be replicated at the client's premises, but I don't want to replicate those library files that aren't part of the client's application, so you would suggest repos `C:\Projects\App1\App1Repo\ ` and  `C:\Projects\Libs\App1LibsRepo\ ` for client 1, and then `C:\Projects\App2\App2Repo\ ` and `C:\Projects\Libs\App2LibsRepo\ ` for client 2, right?  What if I had one repo for client 1 at `C:\Projects\App1Repo\ ` and one repo for client 2 at `C:\Projects\App2Repo\ ` ? Any disadvantages to that approach (other than folder clutter)?

Comment: In general you don't create one repo for two project. Even both projects belong to the same client. It will create problems in future.

Comment: That's not what I mean.  Each project has it's own repo.  So `C:\Projects\App1Repo\ ` references files `C:\Projects\App1\App1.src`,  `C:\Projects\Libs\LibA.src`, `C:\Projects\Libs\LibB.src` and `C:\Projects\App2Repo\ ` references files `C:\Projects\App2\App2.src`,  `C:\Projects\Libs\LibA.src`, `C:\Projects\Libs\LibC.src`. So `LibA.src` is common to both applications, but `LibB.src` only forms a part of Client 1's image, and   `LibC.src` only forms a part of Client 2's image.